# How do I show that $P_{range(A)}$ is an orthogonal projector onto A?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, projection-matrices

I have the first part of the proof, which is that P is indeed an orthogonal projector ($P = P^2 = P^T$). Now, how do I show that $Px \in range(A) \forall x \in R^n$? The linear algebra class I took before numerical was... less than ideal, so I don't know much about the properties of the range.

Comment: What is the definition of $P_{\text{range}}(A)$?

Comment: $P_{range(A)} = A(A^{T}A)^{-1}A^{T}$, I believe! @PkT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$P_{\text{range}(A)}  (x) = A \big( (A^T A)^{-1} A^T x \big) = Ay$, for $y = (A^T A)^{-1} A^Tx $.

$P_{\text{range}(A)}  (x)$ is therefore in the range of $A$, because it is equal to $Ay$ for some $y$.

**Side note:** You are assuming that $(A^TA)$ is invertible, which means that the columns of $A$ are linearly independent. That is not necessarily the case in general.

Comment: Thank you! This is a big help, bit mad at myself for how simple it seems in hindsight though.